# How to insert a row in a table between two existing rows in Sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 9 records in it but i want to insert a row in between of 5th and 6th record.

Comment: Why? Do you not want to order your results when you query the table instead?

Comment: What for? Physical ordering of rows in table storage means nothing to performance and in most databases what you ask is impossible.

Comment: I think he wants to move, for example, song in the list about one position before another song? ...

Comment: your question is not clear though.. share table structure

Answer (score 14):

if you insist on

```
UPDATE mytable SET id = id + 1 where id > 5 ORDER BY id ASC

insert into mytable (id,..) values (6,...)
```

Comment: You need to ORDER BY id DESC so that it increments from the bottom up and avoid duplicate id errors.

Comment: @postelrich that's so right!

Comment: If anyone is looking to do this in sqlite, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54758778/6671004

Answer (score 3):

In general, you don't insert a row at a specific location in a table.

If the row "order" is significant and has some special semantic, have the data reflect that with a proper column in the table structure.

Then use a SELECT ... ORDER BY ... to get rows sorted.